# breezejs: inlineCount when using FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache

Tags: breeze

Would it make sense to add inlineCount to the resultset when the data comes from the cache instead of the server ?

I store the count locally, so as long as don't leave the current url (I use angularjs), I can get it from a variable in my controller. But once I've left that url, if I go back to it, the data will still come from the cache, but my local variable is reset to initial value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update 12 March 2015

The requisite changes have been committed and should make the next release (after 1.5.3).

Of course the `inlineCount` is **only available in async query execution**.

> The synchronous `em.executeQueryLocally(query)` returns immediately with the paged result array; there's no place to hold the `inlineCount`.

Here's an excerpt from the new, corresponding test in DocCode.queryTests: "[can page queried customers in cache with inline count](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode/tests/queryTests.js#L1687)"

```
  var query = EntityQuery.from('Customers')
      .where('CompanyName', 'startsWith', 'A')
      .orderBy('CompanyName')
      .skip(2).take(2)
      .inlineCount()
      .using(breeze.FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache);

  return em.executeQuery(query)
           .then(localQuerySucceeded);

  function localQuerySucceeded(data) {
    var custs = data.results;
    var count = custs.length;
    equal(count, 2,
        "have full page of cached 'A' customers now; count = " + count);

    var inlineCount = data.inlineCount;
    ok(inlineCount && inlineCount > 2,
      'have inlineCount=' + inlineCount + ' which is greater than page size');
  }
```

### Update 9 May 2014

After more reflection, I've decided that you all are right and I have been wrong. I have entered feature request #2267 in our internal tracking system. No promise as to when we'll get it done (soon I trust); stay on us.

### Original

I don't think it makes sense to support `inlineCount` for cache queries because Breeze can't calculate that value.

Walk this through with me. You issue a paged query to the server with the inline count and a page size of 5 items.

```
// Get the first 5 Products beginning with 'C'
// and also get the total of all products beginning with 'C'
var query = EntityQuery.from("Products")
    .where("ProductName", "startsWith", "C")
    .take(5)
    .inlineCount()
    .using(manager);
```

Suppose you run this once and the server reports that there are 142 'C' customers in the database.

Ok now take that same query and execute it locally:

```
query.using(FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache).execute().then(...).fail(...);
```

How is Breeze supposed to know the count? It only has 5 entities in cache. How can it know that there are 142 'C' customers in the database? It can't.

I think you're best option is to check the returned data object to see if it has an `inlineCount` value. Only reset your bound copy of the count if the query went remote.

Comment: It's not an easy one because my bound copy of the count is lost once I move to a different URL (as my angular controller is unloaded). Then when I browse back, there is no bound copy and no inlineCount since the data comes from the cache. I understand though that this is probably beyond the scope of Breeze, although I would have like the inlineCount to be somehow stored in the cache with the dataset.

Comment: Are you encapsulating your client persistence activities in a "Unit of Work" (UoW) service (often called DataContext or DataService)? That would be a natural place to squirrel away that count. UoW is helpful pattern; it's not just for servers.

Comment: @Ward I would have liked inlineCount on local queries to make testing a little easier. [See this question and discussion for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507140/application-with-fake-data-source-for-ui-development/23509156?noredirect=1#comment36129530_23509156).

Comment: You can express the `inlineCount` on local queries; it doesn't break. I suppose we *could* define it and could even give it a value based on the "unpaged" number of entities in cache that satisfy the unbounded query. Maybe that's what you want. I guess we could think about it. But it's really misleading ... which is why we've been reluctant to offer it. And I don't understand how it helps you in testing. Perhaps you could explain how the `inlineCount` value would "make testing a little easier".

Comment: After more reflection, I've decided that *you are right and I have been wrong*. I have entered feature request #2267 in our internal tracking system. No promise as to when we'll get it done (soon I trust); stay on us.

Comment: May I ask about the progress of this feature? When pre-fetching a paged list before the server response arrives, its expensive to calculate accurate inlineCount used for displaying the pager. I essentially have to run a secondary query without `skip` and `take` and get the count of them... This method is not intended to be in production code, it's a workaround, I'm waiting patiently for this to be fixed :) @Ward, thank you all for your hard work, Breeze is awesome ;)

Comment: We haven't gotten to it yet. Frankly, your implementation (2 queries) is close to what we'd have to do under the hood. We'd simply be encapsulating in a single call. So you're not losing that much by doing it yourself.