# Application with fake data source for UI development

Tags: entity-framework, angularjs, breeze

I have a web application with an Angular / Breeze client side calling into a Breeze Web API, which uses an Entity Framework code first model. I have a datacontext (Angular service) responsible for all communications with server.

I would like to completely separate the server development from the client side development so developers need not even have .NET installed on their system. I would like the solution to require very little coding in way of creating fakes, because the app is changing frequently and I do not want to have to rewrite fakes every time my implementation changes. I have a bunch of test data in the database that I would like to make available on the client.

What is a good way (standard way?) to achieve this?

Comment: Mock the data for your responses.  When you make a RESTful request, return a mocked response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my current solution.

1. Get data from the server with a 'unit test' that creates a Breeze Web API controller and uses it to gather the breeze metadata and all the test data from the database, then writes that data to `testData.json` and `breezeMetadata.json`.
2. Abstract the creation of the Breeze Entity Manager to an Angular service `entityManager`.
3. Create a `fakeEntityManager` Angular service, which: 1) creates the entity manager, 2) overrides the EntityManager.executeQuery function to always use the local version, and 3) loads up the mgr with the test data. The code for that service is below.
4. In the `datacontext` service, use the `$injector` service to conditionally inject a real or a fake entity manager.

**datacontext.js**

```
angular.module('app').factory('datacontext', ['$injector','config', datacontext]);

function datacontext($injector, config) {

    if (config.useLocalData === true) {
        var mgr = $injector.get('fakeEntityManager');
    } else var mgr = $injector.get('entityManager');

    ...
```

**fakeEntityManager.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var serviceId = 'fakeEntityManager';
    angular.module('app').factory(serviceId, ['breeze', 'common', em]);

    function em(breeze, common) {
        var $q = common.$q;
        var mgr = getMgr();
        populateManager(["Projects", "People", "Organizations"]);
        return mgr;            

        function getMgr() {
            breeze.EntityManager.prototype.executeQuery = function(query) {
                return $q.when(this.executeQueryLocally(query)).then(function (results) {
                    var data = {
                        results: results
                    };
                    if (query.inlineCountEnabled == true) data.inlineCount = results.length;
                    return data;
                });
            };
            var metaData = < PASTE JSON HERE > 
            new breeze.ValidationOptions({ validateOnAttach: false }).setAsDefault();
            var metadataStore = new breeze.MetadataStore();
            metadataStore.importMetadata(metaData, true);

            return new breeze.EntityManager({
                dataService: new breeze.DataService(
                    {
                        serviceName: "fakeApi",
                        hasServerMetadata: false // don't ask the server for metadata
                    }),
                metadataStore: metadataStore
            });
        }

        function populateManager(resources) {
            var testData = < PASTE JSON HERE >;
            resources.forEach(function (resource) {
                testData[resource].forEach(function (entity) {
                    mgr.createEntity(mgr.metadataStore.getEntityTypeNameForResourceName(resource), entity);
                });
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

If you don't use inlineCount queries there is no need to override executeQuery. You can just add the following property to the EntityManager constructor's parameter:

```
queryOptions: new breeze.QueryOptions({ fetchStrategy: breeze.FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache })
```

Todo: Override the EntityManager.saveChanges() function (or somehow configure the entity manager) to prevent calls to the server while still allowing entities to be edited and saved locally.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. I think your 3rd step of forcing local query can be simplified by just setting the EntityManager queryOptions like so, 
manager.setProperties({
 queryOptions: new breeze.QueryOptions({
   fetchStrategy: breeze.FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache
 })
});

Comment: Thanks @DenisK you are right, but the `FetchStrategy` method of forcing local does not work for me. Not sure why. I will update the answer to show what I think should be the simplest.

Comment: Just to clarify, what I meant was to set the `queryOptions` property on the `EntityManager` instance instead of overriding the `executeQuery` definition. `manager.setProperties({ queryOptions: new breeze.QueryOptions({ fetchStrategy: breeze.FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache }) })`

Comment: Ah no. inlineCount queries broke. Reverting. Think this may be a bug as changing the fetch strategy should not change the format of results. At least I think that is their intent.

Comment: Thanks for reporting it. It looks like inlineCount query is not supported when using local cache fetch strategy. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935885/breezejs-inlinecount-when-using-fetchstrategy-fromlocalcache for further explanation.

Comment: What do you mean "inlineCount queries broke"? There is no exception. There just isn't any `inlineCount` value in the returned object (because we don't know what value to give it). You should be able to deal with its absence in a way that doesn't break your tests or your code.

Comment: Faking the save is tricky. Are you comfortable with throwing an exception if someone tries to save? If so, I can give you the recipe for that at a low level ... although I'm wondering why you wouldn't have a mock `DataContext` that threw if anything called *its* `save` method. Lots of ways (too many?) to skin this cat.

Comment: @Ward thanks very much for your replies. I do not mean inlineQueries broke in the sense that they are not working as they should. I mean they are not working the way I want with the mock data. I could, as you say, just handle the absence of inlineCount but I would then be adding logic that only serves the mock version, and I would like to keep all such logic within a single fakeEntityManager. I could have a single fake datacontext instead, but that would be much more code. I like the way Breeze makes it really easy to create a very functional mock data service.

Comment: I agree and have scheduled a fix for this, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935885/breezejs-inlinecount-when-using-fetchstrategy-fromlocalcache

Answer (score 1):

Just create mocks.  You don't even have to make a RESTful call if you don't want to, just have your service decide whether to hit the server or pull from cache and load up your cache locally on start -

```
function loadMocks (manager) {
    var personMockOne = manager.createEntity('Person', { id: 1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith' });
    var companyMockOne = manager.createEntity('Company', { id: 1, name: 'Acme Inc.' });
    companyMockOne.employees.push(personMockOne);
}
```

http://pwkad.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/creating-mocks-with-breeze-js/

**To Expand...**

Doing this requires a bit of extra set up.  I personally always write my queries separate from my controller / view model logic through a service which takes parameters.  A few example parameters are always something like `parameters` and `forceRemote`.  The idea is that when you go to execute the query you can decide whether to hit the server or query locally.  A quick example -

```
function queryHereOrThere (manager, parameters, forceRemote) {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery().from('EntityName').using(manager);
    query.where(parameters);

    if (!forceRemote) {
        query.executeQueryLocally();
    } else {
        query.executeQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what happens when your code calls `manager.executeQuery(someQuery)`? Does it not go looking for the server?

Comment: Added some more information to my answer, hope it helps

Comment: Ack your addition of `queryHereOrThere`. I am still a little concerned that when you call `queryHereOrThere` you will have to check configuration (e.g config.test = true) to know whether to ensure it doesn't go remote. I would rather only have to check that config once and then inject something, perhaps a fake entity manager pre-loaded with its `executeQuery` method overridden. I'm working on that now.

Comment: No, that is the purpose of the `forceRemote` variable.  The query is just a fake query so imagine `getPeople` instead of `queryHereOrThere`.  In fact take it a step further and pass in an entityType so you can just reuse the query for ALL your queries.